# Using javascript conditions to hide elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code, I have two elements; an input box with id 'alpha' and a paragraph with id 'bravo'. What I'm trying to do is make bravo invisible when there is nothing in the input box alpha.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("alpha");
            var b = document.getElementById("bravo");
            window.onload = function hidebravo() {
                if (a.value == nil) {b.style.visibility = "hidden";}
                }
            a.onchange = function hidebravo() {
                if (a.value == nil) {b.style.visibility = "hidden";}
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="alpha"/>
        <p id="bravo">Hello!</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

For sake of clarity, I have set the variables 'a' and 'b' to correspond to the JS selectors for the input box and the paragraph, respectively.

Now, as soon as the window is loaded I call the function 'hidebravo()' which is the function that makes bravo invisible ***if*** input box alpha is empty. I call the same function whenever the user changes the value of alpha, in case alpha contains a value which the user then deletes and it becomes empty once again.

But, for whatever reason, this isn't working as it should and I can't figure out why.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use null instead of nil in Javascript.

Here's the code that works, without window.onload function:

JS:

```
function reloadBravo() {
  var bravoParagraph = document.getElementById('bravo');
  var alphaTextBox = document.getElementById('alpha');
  var alphaText = alphaTextBox.value;

  if (alphaText.length > 0) {
    bravoParagraph.innerHTML = alphaText;
    bravoParagraph.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    bravoParagraph.innerHTML = '';
    bravoParagraph.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="alpha" onkeyup="reloadBravo()"/>
    <p id="bravo"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm now using the length property instead and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input id="alpha"/>
        <p id="bravo">Hello!</p>
        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("alpha");
            var b = document.getElementById("bravo");
            window.onload = function hidebravo() {
                if (a.value == "")
                   b.style.visibility = "hidden";
                else
                   b.style.visibility =  "visible";
                    
                }
            a.oninput = function hidebravo() {
                if (a.value == "") 
                    b.style.visibility = "hidden";
                else
                    b.style.visibility =  "visible";
                    
                }
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have special `nil` value. There is `null`. But the `.value` property of the `HTMLInputElement` is a `DOMString` and can't be `null`. You need to check the `.length` property of the `DOMString`. `length` of `0` indicates that there is no set `value`.

```
if (a.value.length === 0) { ... }
```

Note that as an space and a tab is considered a character, you need to trim the value for checking whether user has typed any visible characters or not:

```
if (a.value.trim().length === 0) { ... }
```

But that's not the only problem. `load` event is fired once and your code doesn't check the current value of the inputs. You should add an event handler for `keyup`/`input`/`change`/`paste`/... events fired for the input elements.

```
a.addEventListener('keyup', hidebravo);    
b.addEventListener('keyup', hidebravo);
```